# How to fetch ScheduleState and StoryType for a User Story in Rally

Tags: rally

I am trying to create a Custom HTML grid to show a list of all user stories with their different properties including name, id, schedule states and story types.
I am not getting the state and the type somehow, getting the id and name and some other fields.

Heres the code snippet for fetching them:

```
onScopeChange: function() {
    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
        model: 'UserStory',
        fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','State', 'Type','TestCases'],
        pageSize: 100,
        autoLoad: true,
        filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
        listeners: {
            load: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        }
    }); 
},

 _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
            var stories = [];
            var pendingTestCases = data.length;

            Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                        var s  = {
                            FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                            Name: story.get('Name'),
                            _ref: story.get("_ref"),                                
                            State: story.get('ScheduleState'),
                            Type: story.get('StoryType'),
                            TestCaseCount: story.get('TestCases').Count,
                            TestCases: []
                        };
```

Comment: Got it. I should have used the following code:                           fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','ScheduleState', 'StoryType','TestCases']

Answer (score 0):

your fetch does not include 'ScheduleState' :

```
fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','State', 'Type','TestCases'],
```

ScheduleState shows as State in the UI to keep it short, but in the WS API it is referred to as ScheduleState. Please check with [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) for names of fields. Find HierarchicalRequirement in the object model.

Also you refer to Type as Type in the fetch and as StoryType later. Based on the name, it looks like this is a custom field. In WS API it would have c_ prepended.